# Unable to validate form elements

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trynig to learn how to validate form elements using their IDs. I also made a fiddle to check and try manipulating the code but the fiddle is showing error. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/obz3jc30/ There is definitely something wrong in the code because of which I am unable to validate. Need help in identifying the issue

HTML

```
<form name="Form1">
Age : 
<input value="" name="Fromage" type="text" id="Fromage">
&nbsp;to&nbsp;
<input value="" name="Toage" type="text" id="Toage">
<button class="check" onclick="function()">Validate</button> 
</form>
```

Script

```
$('.check').click(function() {
        var af=Form1.Fromage.value;
        if (af.length == 0 )
        {           
            alert( "Please Enter Age From." );  
            Form1.Fromage.focus( );
            return false;
        }
        if(h.length>0)
        {
          if((af.length<2)||(af.length>2))
      {
        alert( "Age should be 2 digits");   
            Form1.Fromage.focus( );
            return false;       
      }
      else
      {
            var af3=/[^1-9]/;
        if(af.match(af3)!=null)
        {
            alert( "Please Enter Valid Age");   
            Form1.Fromage.focus( );
            return false;
        }
      }       
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: your code (fiddle) lacks much. first of all: add jquery to fiddle. then: remove eventlistener from html. then: add ); to the end of the selfinvocing function. Now I am stuck with "What the heck is `h`". Here's an updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/obz3jc30/1/ To be honest: Read your basics of js again please, and then I'd suggest using a good form validation plugin for jquery or html5 validation tools. (just google), and use your browsers debugger to check what'S going on line by line.

Comment: `h.length` was by mistake. sorry but i did not understand add jquery to fiddle. then: remove eventlistener from html. I will google that. Saw the updated fiddle. Thank you so much

Comment: what do you mean by `h.length` ??, in your code  `h.length` doesn't make any sense. is `h.length` be replaced by `af.length`???

Comment: Yes i replaced it. thanks